# Non-static method App\User::products() should not be called statically

Tags: php, sql, laravel, orm, frameworks

I don't know why I am getting this error:

```
Non-static method App\User::products() should not be called statically
```

This is my controller method:

```
    public function create()
{
    $users = User::products('name', 'id');
    return view('products.create')->with('users', $users);
}
```

This is my model

```
    <?php
  
namespace App;
  
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use Kyslik\ColumnSortable\Sortable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use HasRoles;
    use Sortable;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'surname', 'showname', 'business', 'NIP', 'PESEL', 'address', 'city', 'postalcode', 'phone', 'comments', 
    ];
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
  
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
    
    public $sortable = ['name',
                        'email',
                         'surname', 
                        'showname', 
                        'business',
                        'address',
                        'city',
                        'phone',
                        'role',
                       ];
    
        public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
        public function invoices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Invoice');
    }
}
```

Can you help me? I am trying to do dynamic dependency dropdown menu in view with this. Want to get user names and id from user model for dropdown in view and than connect products with users and save data to product table with user id.

Comment: `products` is a relation of the user model, it's not some static method that you can call using `User` model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relationships is to be called on models, so you have to fetch them from a user model. Change your controller logic to just fetch users, not anything with products.

```
public function create()
{
    $users = User::all();
    return view('products.create')->with('users', $users);
}
```

So in your blade file where you create your drop down, loop the users and then you can loop the products.

```
@foreach($users as $user)

    @foreach($user->products as $product) // fetch products
        // do your magic
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```